# Disaster Recovery Azure Resource Group Region Down What Happens

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

Just wondering what happens when an Azyre region goes down? It states in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview#resource-groups)

> If the resource group's region is temporarily unavailable, you can't update resources in the resource group because the metadata is unavailable. The resources in other regions will still function as expected, but you can't update them. For more information about building reliable applications, see Designing reliable Azure applications.

This to me reads that all resources in that region are in a read only mode meaning we can't modify the resource however we can still for exaple write to app insights?

However, if I have a resource group situated in **EUN** and it contains resources for multiple regions (**EUN** and **EUW**) what happens to the resources in this resource group?

*I know its not correct to bundle multiple resources in a single resource group but its hangover from work done previously*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is correct. In such a scenario a resource in the online region can't be modified but will continue to function.

If you have a resource group in a region and that resource group contains resources from another region those resources will be online but you will not be able to update them.

For example, you have a resource group in West US 2 and it contains 2 Function Apps, one in West US 2 and one in East US. The Function in West US 2 will be offline because the region is offline. The Function in East US will be available but you will be unable to update it.